# ValueError in random.randrange 

Tags: python, random

```
def wordjumble(Wordlist, Hintlist, score):
    wordchoice = getword(Wordlist, Hintlist)
    high = len(wordchoice)
    low = -len(wordchoice)
    for i in range(10):
        position = random.randrange(high,low)
        print wordchoice[position]
    score = wordguess(wordchoice, score)
    return score
```

I receive a value error, my task is to get a random number between high and low.
Where is my mistake?

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "E:\Programming\Python\Worksheet 15\test.py", line 54, in
wordjumble(Wordlist, Hintlist, score) 
File "E:\Programming\Python\Worksheet 15\test.py", line 49, in wordjumble
position = random.randrange(high,low) 
File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.2.1\App\lib\random.py", line 217, in
randrange raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)"
% (istart, istop, width) ValueError: empty range for randrange() (7,-7, -14)
```

Comment: Yes, where *is* your mistake? :-) .. can you provide the Traceback/error message you get?

Comment: Read the documentation for [random.randrange](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange).

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Worksheet 15\test.py", line 54, in <module>
    wordjumble(Wordlist, Hintlist, score)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Worksheet 15\test.py", line 49, in wordjumble
    position = random.randrange(high,low)
  File "E:\Portable Python 2.7.2.1\App\lib\random.py", line 217, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (7,-7, -14)

Comment: @Geostigmata This should be part of your question, not a comment. Please edit your question to include the traceback.

Comment: In future, if you ask a question like this, try and include a full, working code sample (in this case, it isn't clear what arguments you are passing to the function) and the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line

```
        position = random.randrange(high,low)
```

to

```
        position = random.randrange(low,high)
```

ETA: There are other problems with this code. If `wordchoice` is a single word (as is implied by the `getword` function), then what your loop is doing is picking a random number between `-len(wordchoice)` and `len(wordchoice)-1`. If you're trying to get a random letter from the word, it would be simpler to do a random number between `0` and `len(wordchoice)-1`, and even simpler just to do `random.choice(wordchoice)`.

It looks like the loop is picking 10 random letters from the word and printing them (each on a separate line). That means that using the word `the` would end up with a "jumble" something like:

```
h
t
t
e
h 
e
t
e
t
e
```

This always has 10 letters, and doesn't guarantee that it uses each letter of the word once (which is probably necessary for your jumble). If rather than picking 10 letters with replacement, you want it to jumble the word by changing the order of the letters (as is implied by the title of the function, `wordjumble`), check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668312/shuffle-string-in-python) for a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because you reversed the arguments on line:

```
 position = random.randrange(high,low)
```

it should be:

```
 position = random.randrange(low,high)
```

Advice: Most of the python reference documents show examples of the code. Check them out first as they might help you right away:
http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

Kind regards,
Bo

Answer (score 0):

```
   random.randrange([start], stop[, step])
   Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This is equivalent to          choice(range(start, stop, step)), but doesn’t actually build a range object.
```

Comment: I'm considerably new to python and programming in general there for I'm sorry for a newbie questions. Can anyone give me an example how to fix it?

Comment: random.randrange(low,high) Insted of  random.randrange(high,low)

Comment: How about some word wrapping?

Comment: Basically what happens is: that function gives you nothing and when you try to use the value it gave you, python complains because it was made to be that way. Unlike other languages, Python is very careful not to let things like segmentation faults happen and things that, when they happen in C, you cry for hours in front of your screen.

Comment: @Flo: why don't you update your answer to include all these explanations?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not used to stackoverflow and it's conventions. I still have to wrap my head around it :)

Answer (score 0):

In general ranges are given with `low` to `high`, you man want to check the [randrange docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html?highlight=randrange#random.randrange).

You can find *simple* usage examples [at Python Number randrange() Function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_randrange.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `high,low` with `low,high`:

```
def wordjumble(Wordlist, Hintlist, score):
    wordchoice = getword(Wordlist, Hintlist)
    high = len(wordchoice)
    low = -len(wordchoice)
    for i in range(10):
        position = random.randrange(low,high)
        print wordchoice[position]
    score = wordguess(wordchoice, score)
    return score
```