# Anybody know how to shuffle two strings together?

Tags: python

How to shuffle to inputted strings, and to mix together to jumble the two strings up.
For example "hello" and "world" shuffle together to become "wherd llohe"

Comment: Do you know how to scramble one string? do you know how to concat 2 strings? If so then combine the two solutions.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 1):

As @DeepSpace suggested, you can first concatenate the two words, then shuffle them. Additionally, you might want to 'preserve' the length of your original words (that's the reason for the additional statement before the return).

```
import random

def shuffle_words(word_a, word_b):
    word = word_a + word_b
    lst = list(word)
    random.shuffle(lst)
    shuffled_word = ''.join(lst[:len(word_a)]) + ' ' + ''.join(lst[len(word_a):]) 
    return shuffled_word
```

You can then call this function as:

```
shuffle_words('hello', 'world')
>>> 'elolw lhrdo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668312/shuffle-string-in-python)

The below should work for you:

```
import random
string1 = "hello"
string2 = "world"
''.join(random.sample(string1,len(string1))) + ' ' + ''.join(random.sample(string2,len(string2)))
```

Comment: This approach does not mix the words, right?

Answer (score 0):

the hard way,

- get the ascii equivalent of each letter
- generate a random letter between the range of highest and lowest ascii value
- join the random characters together

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
word1 = "hello"
word2 = "world"
new_word = word1+word2
result = ''.join(random.sample(new_word ,len(new_word )))
#  'loolehdwlr'
```

Comment: However, this approach does not produce two words as requested by the OP.