# How to create a new string of a string with different combination

Tags: python, string

I have a string of characters in order of English alphabets
`alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` and I want to generate a new set of alphabets in which each character is presented by a random character (finding another unique combination of this string) in Python.

I tried using random but in some of the generations there are more than one of each character

```
    for i in range(n):
        tempString = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=26))
        pop.append(tempString)
```

Comment: Would simply shuffling the letters around accomplish the same outcome you're after?  In this way, they are guaranteed to be unique ... providing the original string contains unique letters.  [Here is a another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2668312/6340496) which addresses this.

Comment: are you looking for shuffle the string alphabet

Comment: Yes, I guess that's what I want, can you help me with the code? @S3DEV

Comment: @mohammedwazeem yes I guess

Comment: How much is n  ?

Comment: @azro number of alphabets 26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use [`from random import shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the alphabet

```
new_alphabet = list(alphabet)
shuffle(new_alphabet)
new_alphabet = "".join(new_alphabet)

print(new_alphabet)  # evpjafimnhoszuqwgkxtcldryb
```

Or use [`from random import sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) which gives `k` uniques element from the population, so if you give the total size of the population, it's do like shuffling

```
new_alphabet = sample(alphabet, k=len(alphabet))
new_alphabet = "".join(new_alphabet)

print(new_alphabet)  # tulkyjrzeabofpnvsqmgwxhdic
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sample` function from random module

```
import random

a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
print(''.join(random.sample(a,len(a))))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  use [more_itertools.random_permutation](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.random_permutation):

```
from more_itertools import random_permutation

n = 2
pop = [''.join(random_permutation(ascii_uppercase)) for _ in range(n)]
pop
```

output:

```
['RCWAYMZIDXQTONEJSGUHBFVLKP', 'SCQJAEGVXFRTUPZBHIWDNMLYKO']
```

Comment: This is identical to my answer :)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco no, where do you see str.join?

Comment: Right. but if you try to execute this function it does not work (in python 3.7.5). You should edit  it or remove it

Comment: @RiccardoBucco thx, I hope now is better