# How to shuffle the letters of string in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, random, shuffle

```
from random import shuffle
string = 'String'
shuffle(string)
print(string)
```

*Its not working!*
*There is any other way.*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please elaborate what does it mean "it is not working". What is the expected and what is the observed behaviour / output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shuffle string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668312/shuffle-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert string into a list. This is how you use shuffle

```
from random import shuffle

string = 'String'
l = list(string)
shuffle(l)
string = ''.join(l)
print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a even shorter version:

```
import random
s="String"
print(''.join(random.sample(s,len(s))))
```